# Finding the Nash equilibrium for applied first price sealed bid auction

Tags: game-theory, economics

I need to answer following questions. [image]

Though all questions are puzzling to me, my core questions are

1. How can I get mixed strategy Nash equilibrium of type $v^*$? What is the exact distribution function of bidding?
2. Do the players use different strategy depending on whether they draw value from uniform distribution, or their values are determined equaling $v^*$?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.